# How to convert pandas dataframe to tensorflow dataset?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, tensorflow

I am reading a csv file into a pandas dataframe.

```
train_data = pd.read_csv('mnist_test.csv');
```

Sample data

```
   label  pixel1  pixel2  pixel3  ...  pixel781  pixel782  pixel783  pixel784
0      6     149     149     150  ...       106       112       120       107
1      5     126     128     131  ...       184       184       182       180
2     10      85      88      92  ...       226       225       224       222
3      0     203     205     207  ...       230       240       253       255
4      3     188     191     193  ...        49        46        46        53
```

how can I convert this dataframe into a tensorflow dataset.

Comment: Tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe
PS: Note that the MNIST dataset already exists in the datasets catalog: https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/catalog/mnist

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import tensorflow as tf
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(dict(train_data))
```

See [tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/pandas_dataframe) for details.

Comment: Add an explanation to your answer rather than linking to another source!

Comment: now you need to use .to_dict() instead of dict()

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness,

```py
import tensorflow as tf
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(train_data.to_dict(orient="list"))
print(ds)
TensorSliceDataset element_spec={'label': TensorSpec(shape=(), dtype=tf.int32, name=None), ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from datasets import load_dataset

dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files='my_file.csv')

dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files=['my_file_1.csv', 'my_file_2.csv', 'my_file_3.csv'])

dataset = load_dataset('csv', data_files={'train': ['my_train_file_1.csv', 'my_train_file_2.csv'],'test': 'my_test_file.csv'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this if you want to convert whole df

```
ratings = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(df[['label','pixel1'..]].values)
ratings = ratings.map(lambda x: {"label": x[0],"pixel1": x[1],....})
```